# How to correctly configure Django to send emails with Gmail and what are the correct settings for the Gmail account?

Tags: python, django, email, gmail

I would appreciate some help with setting up Gmail with a Django application.
I am trying to send send an email using gmail through Django to reset user passwords.
My settings.py SMTP configuration is:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myemail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASWORD = 'mypassword'
```

For the password I tried using both, the actual account password and the generated 16 digit password for apps which don't support 2-step authentication. I enabled the IMAP access and access for less secure apps in my gmail settings. I am still getting this error when trying to reset the password on my Django app:

> SMTPSenderRefused at /reset/
> (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError s21sm6387949wmc.10 - gsmtp', 'webmaster@localhost')

Any ideas what am I doing wrong? I am not sure if this is an issue with my configuration in Django or Gmail settings. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable IMAP from gmail settings : take a look [here](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?p=WantAuthError&visit_id=637558317160685889-2408795464&rd=2#cantsignin)

> Step 1: Check that IMAP is turned on 1-On your computer, open Gmail.
>
> 2-In the top right, click Settings Settings and then See all
> settings.
>
> 3-Click the Forwarding and POP/IMAP tab.
>
> 4-In the "IMAP access" section, select Enable IMAP.
>
> 5-Click Save Changes.

Comment: Thanks but I have already done it as I explained in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking "Trusted devices" in GSuite/Gmail configuration, first time sending an email form new device needs to be approved in the configuration panel.

Comment: You cannot add devices manually, all you can do is generate a 16 digit password for apps that don't support 2 factor authentication. I tried using both, the 16 digit password and the normal password of my account.

Comment: @Arnas did you ever get this figured out? Im having the exact same issue you are having.